# VSCode Extension to underline certain keywords

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to make a new VSCode Extension that can help flag keywords by underlining them and suggesting alternatives.

I've been looking through the Extension docs and thought I'd find it in the Language Extensions section but seemingly no such luck:
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/overview

Anyone know what this "underline and suggest" feature is actually called or where I could find more info?

Comment: search the docs for `Decoration`, `createTextEditorDecorationType()`

Comment: Have a look at the source code for the Highlight extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight or similar.

Comment: Thanks both! Appreciate the pointers!